# Windows 10 lockout time (via registry)

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-10

Anyone know how to set the lockout duration (for Windows 10), via the registry? I'm having a heck of a time finding the right key.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RemoteAccess\Parameters\AccountLockout**

This is technically where the lockout duration is set in the registry.

**NOTE:** I highly **do not** recommend editing the registry as a method of changing lockout information.  Edit a GPO or local GPO for that, it's easier to undo if something goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at that key. The PCs are members of a workgroup and the deployment configuration is automated via a Powershell script that runs the first time an admin logs in. If there is better way to change the setting, that I can put in that PS script, I'm all for it.

Comment: Powershell has a lot of wonderful GPO related commands that **only** run on servers.  I have yet to find a single GPO command that runs directly on the workstation.  So, until they fix that, this is probably the way to go.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-get-account-lockout-and-password-policy/   (this was written in 2014, question from 2016, now it's 2019, time flies....)